# Sending the html code of a canvas in client web page to server?

Tags: image, canvas, client

this may be a stupid question.. but i decided to give it a try here...

i am developing a web application using AJAX to do the interactions between client and server(python/django).

now in the client page, there is a canvas which contains a dynamically generated image; i want to get this image and send this image to server, however, i can't use Canvas.toDataURL() due to the violation of canvas security rule (client and server must be in same domain in this case).

so I am just wondering whether it's possible to get the canvas element and send its HTML back to server, then let server process it and extract its image data?

appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 0):

The only problem if the `<canvas>` date is tained by using images from different origins (CORS problem).

Just

- Use toDataURL() to get the image data
- Post this data to the server using normal AJAX
- Strip off data URL prefix
- base64 decode the data
- Now you have image data in binary format
- Do whatever you wish with the image

base64 + dataURL decode example: https://github.com/miohtama/Krusovice/blob/master/bin/create_bg_thumbnails.py#L62

Comment: i know this workflow. but as mentioned in the question, i am looking for a way to get around this canvas security issue(CORS problem), that 's why I am wondering whether it's workable to send the whole Canvas element in html to server and let server to extract image data.